# validation for already saved data to mysql using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to save skills having by the employee. I did validation in model like

```
validates :skill_name,:presence=>{:message=>" cannot be blank"},
                :uniqueness=> { scope: :employee_id}
```

This not shown in page. bcoz its render as js not a html. I use code in controller as like,

```
if @emp_skill.save!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to employee_profile_path(current_user.associated_id), notice: 'Successfully Saved.' }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to employee_profile_path(current_user.associated_id), notice: 'Not Saved.' }
    end
  end
```

I want to run as like "show as html" but this runs as "show as JS".

> Processing by EmployeeProfilesController#show as JS

I want to display the flash message and refresh the page

**OR**
Using java script, want to validate. skills already exist means, the message or alert wants to shown like "Skill already saved". I get the placement value, but I cannot know how to compare the value with database value. if not exist means the value saved else the alert wants to display. How to check and validate  with mySql value with input value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give the redirection link into the script. like

```
**window.location.assign(empId);**
```

This makes the redirection and flash the error message after refresh the page.
Thanks. :)